# EntityFrameword Wizard не хочет работать с SQlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework

Пытаюсь создать Entity Data Model из SQLite базы. Подключение происходит без проблем. В Server Explorer вижу как соединение так и содержимое базы. Но на переходе к последнему этапу, где мне нужно выбрать таблицу, окно просто закрывается и модель конечно не создается. 
[image: описание]

На изображении показан этап, до которого Entity Ftamework Wizard не доходит, просто вылетая.

Comment: У вас в свойствах проекта случайно не выставлено Any CPU ?

Comment: @Bulson Точно так.

Comment: могу ошибаться, но при работе с SQLite надо выбрать конкретную архитектуру, попробуйте выставить x86.

Comment: @Bulson Не помогло к сожалению. Кто тому-же насколько я понимаю, целевая архитектура влияет на проект только в момент сборки.